# Network Drive disconnect prompt on wake

Tags: finder, imac, sleep-wake

I'm investigating bringing OS X onto our windows network at the moment, which, despite a few hiccups, has been going pretty well! (A lot better than some of my colleagues suggested it would!).

I've got network drives mapping and functioning fine, however one of our corporate policies is that the machine goes to sleep/locks every 15 minutes. 
I'm finding that on wake, the drives are still connected, however I have a prompt that the network connection was interrupted and to disconnect the drives:

[image: Disconnect Prompt]

I can click to disconnect the drives, or open finder and re-access the drive, which clears the message. 
This is the state exactly after wake:
(You can see the drive is actively mapped, but there's still a prompt to disconnect)
[image: OnWake]

It's no hassle for me to open finder, but in the context of end users, I'm hoping to be able to stop that disconnected drive message from appearing on wake.

Any suggestions?

Note: Using OS X 10.10.1

Comment: Would this article help you ? http://www.bluepiccadilly.com/2012/10/mac-os-x-automatically-connect-network-drive-when-your-computer-starts-or-wakes-sleep

Comment: Thanks for the response Buscar, I had a look at that solution yesterday and while I think it will achieve what i'm trying to achieve, I've already got the drives re-connecting at log-on and am just trying to get rid of the prompt to avoid end users *accidentally* disconnecting their home drive when they log-in.
Trying to get a screenshot of the prompt now to assist.

Comment: Any idea who is generating the prompt (look in Console if a indication is there)

Comment: Not certain where the prompt is coming from. Just had a trawl through Console and found the following, which seems to relate to my network drives: 

mds: (FMW.Error:812) FMW FSE_CONTENT_MODIFIED uid/gid -1 /Volumes/Shared

Had a bit of a search but couldn't find anything to suggest a cause for this. I've also updated the OP with some more details and a screenshot.

Comment: After a bit of further investigation and testing, i'm inclined to think it's a result of the network adapter taking 10 - 20 seconds to initialize, receive DHCP and begin talking again/the PC doing a mobile log-in until the network has initialized properly.  
If the PC has only just locked/gone to sleep, I can wake up, log-in and access my network drives instantly.

Comment: Confirming my above post. Seems to be if I give the network adapter 30 seconds to wake up, before logging in, the drives come across without error. 

Bit out of scope to go modifying anything here, so i'll just warn end users to allow for a minute or so on wake, unless we decide to implement significantly more than 5 OS X Machines on our network.

Comment: Great, you might want to make that a answer.

Answer (score 1):

Confirming my above post. Seems to be if I give the network adapter 30 seconds to wake up, before logging in, the drives come across without error. Bit out of scope to go modifying anything here, so i'll just warn end users to allow for a minute or so on wake, unless we decide to implement significantly more than 5 OS X Machines on our network.